# Hide relationship on Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I need your suggestion about better way to hide information from relationship array.

```
$members = User::with('profile')->paginate(9);

$members->makeHidden([
    'slug', 'profile.avatar'
]);

dd($members->toArray());
```

This code doesn't hide information from profile array.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`makeHidden` isn't supported for relationship properties, only the entire relationship. Instead, take what you want:

```
$member = User::with(['profile' => $function($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'about');
}])->paginate(9);
```

The above would only give you the `id`, `user_id`, and `about` fields explicitly, for example.

**Edit**

If you're using `5.6` you can define the columns as a comma separated string, too:

```
$member = User:with('profile:id,user_id,about')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach. It returns profile as null

Comment: @seoppc I forgot the `user_id`. Updated.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id, user_id, about" does not exist

Comment: select accepts an array, add a `[` and `]` around the columns.

Comment: @seoppc Yikes, looks like you `concatenated` all the columns as a string, like `'id, user_id, about'` instead of `'id', 'user_id', 'about'`

Comment: @Devon No need with a `->select()` only with `->get()`

Comment: This seems to be working but now I can't access to Mutators.  This is really an issue :(

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. It works for mutators with $value as param but not for following `public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}`

Comment: @seoppc Are you saying that `getFullNameAttribute` stops working on  your `User`?

Comment: It doesn't get included on JSON output - yes I am using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 2):

Add them to your model itself.

*When hiding relationships, use the relationship's method name.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

This will fix you up

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json